# Python 3 Testing a range of items within a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, if-statement

I have a list, or array, called inventory[] and it has a maximum of fifteen entries at any given time. I need to test if any of these entries is equal to zero, and if any one entry is equal to zero, do something. What is an efficient way to do this without doing

```
if inventory[0] == 0 or inventory[1] == 0 or inventory[2] == 0...
```

etc.?

Comment: "test if any of these entries is equal to zero, and if any one entry is equal to zero, do something." is confusing. What is the difference between "any of these entries" and "any one entry"? Do WHAT something -- something in general, or something in particular with one/some/all zero entries, for which you will need to know the position (index) of a zero entry in the list?

Answer (score 5):

For your simple case, I think you could possibly just do this:

```
if 0 in inventory:
  # do something
```

For a more general case for this type of thing, you can use the `any` function ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any)).

```
if any([item == 0 for item in inventory]):
  # do something
```

Comment: +1 for the `if 0 in inventory`. Sometimes one forgets the easier things :)

Answer (score 2):

Python's built-in [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) function is perfect for this.  It takes an iterable as an argument and returns `True` if any of the elements are true (non-falsy).

```
if any(item == 0 for item in inventory):
    # do something
```

There is also a similar function called `all()` that will return `True` if all elements are True.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `all` function, and the fact that `0` evaluates as `False`:

```
if not all(inventory):
    ...
```

Edit: assuming that `inventory` contains only numbers, of course

Comment: Fragile, could break for example with `inventory = ['spam', [], 'eggs']`

Comment: @wim: of course; I'm assuming `inventory` is a list of integers (and that's why there's a 0 there)

Comment: It's best not to make such assumptions, if they aren't needed, or at least mention the assumptions in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
inventory=[1,2,3,4,0]
if 0 in inventory:
 print "There is 0 in the list"
```

output: 
There is 0 in the list